# Flask + Bokeh AjaxDataSource

Tags: flask, bokeh

Struggling with Flask + Bokeh AjaxDataSource:

I have a function that returns json data:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def get_x():
    global x, y
    x = x + 0.1
    y = math.sin(x)
    return flask.jsonify(x=[x], y=[y])
```

I can use use it with a Bokeh AjaxDataSource no problem to create a streaming plot:

```
source = AjaxDataSource(data_url="http://localhost:5000/data", polling_interval=1000, mode='append')
p = figure()
p.line('x', 'y', source=source)                                                                       
show(p)
```

However, when I try to embed this in a flask page, the AjaxDataSource does not query the server.  The plot fails to render with no errors.  Note that if I use a static plot instead of an AjaxDataSource, it plots fine.  Here's the relevant code:

```
template = Template('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Streaming Example</title>
        {{ js_resources }}
        {{ css_resources }}
    </head>
    <body>
    {{ plot_div }}
    {{ plot_script }}
    </body>
</html>
''')

@app.route("/")
def simple():
    streaming=True
    source = AjaxDataSource(data_url="http://localhost:5000/data", 
                            polling_interval=1000, mode='append')

    fig = figure(title="Streaming Example")
    fig.line( 'x', 'y', source=source)

    js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
    css_resources = INLINE.render_css()

    script, div = components(fig, INLINE)

    html = template.render(
        plot_script=script,
        plot_div=div,
        js_resources=js_resources,
        css_resources=css_resources
    )

    return encode_utf8(html)
```

If anyone has any thoughts, I'd be thankful.

Brian

Comment: I would add that there is an official example in the bokeh repo: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.2.0/examples/howto/ajax_source.py.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, as a gentle suggestion, please always post *complete* runnable code examples. It took a few minutes to reproduce all the missing necessary imports, for something that only took seconds to diagnose once there was a runnable script.

---

*UPDATE: Since Bokeh `0.12.15` the workaround described below should not be required. `AjaxDataSource` should stream without complaint into an empty CDS with no empty columns created up front.*

---

Recently some of the BokehJS code paths were made more "strict" which is good in almost every instance, but it appears this left a bad interaction with `AjaxDataSource` that was not noticed. FWIW when I run example I do see an error in the *browser* JS console:

```
Error: attempted to retrieve property array for nonexistent field 'x'
```

And this is the key to the workround, which is just to make sure the data source does have (empty) columns for `x` and `y`:

```
source.data = dict(x=[], y=[])
```

There is a complete working script below. I'd ask that you please make an issue on the [Bokeh issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with this information so that this bug can be prioritized and fixed

---

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from jinja2 import Template
import math

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import AjaxDataSource
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.resources import INLINE


app = Flask(__name__)

x, y = 0, 0

@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def get_x():
    global x, y
    x = x + 0.1
    y = math.sin(x)
    return jsonify(x=[x], y=[y])

template = Template('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Streaming Example</title>
        {{ js_resources }}
        {{ css_resources }}
    </head>
    <body>
    {{ plot_div }}
    {{ plot_script }}
    </body>
</html>
''')

@app.route("/")
def simple():
    streaming=True
    source = AjaxDataSource(data_url="http://localhost:5000/data",
                            polling_interval=1000, mode='append')

    source.data = dict(x=[], y=[])

    fig = figure(title="Streaming Example")
    fig.line( 'x', 'y', source=source)

    js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
    css_resources = INLINE.render_css()

    script, div = components(fig, INLINE)

    html = template.render(
        plot_script=script,
        plot_div=div,
        js_resources=js_resources,
        css_resources=css_resources
    )

    return html

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This worked perfectly.  I'll post an issue as you suggested.  Brian.

Comment: I want to use the render_template and have the html file using jinja2 template.  My html file is like this:    {% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %} 
<div class="container">
 <div>
        {{ script | safe}}
        {{ div | safe}}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}.  When I replace the return encode(html) with return render_template('testajax.html', script = script, div = div), I gt this error: WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a Bokeh issue. Perhaps you have the file you are wanting to write to open in another process, maybe an editor?

Answer (score 8):

Like the OP, I also wanted to use AJAX with Bokeh and Flask. However, instead of continuously streaming the data from the server with `AjaxDataSource` I wanted to get the new data from the server only when user interacts with the inputs on the web page. To accomplish this, I used bigreddot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101669/5524090) as a basis, changed `AjaxDataSource` to `ColumnDataSource` and added a jQuery AJAX call inside `CustomJS` (the following example has been created with Python 3.6.4, Flask 1.0.2 and Bokeh 0.13.0):

```py
import json

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from jinja2 import Template
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.util.string import encode_utf8

app = Flask(__name__)

N_DATAPOINTS = 20
DEFAULT_VARIABLE = 'bar'
MY_DATABASE = {
    'foo': [i**1 for i in range(N_DATAPOINTS)],
    'bar': [i**2 for i in range(N_DATAPOINTS)],
    'baz': [i**3 for i in range(N_DATAPOINTS)]}


@app.route("/get_new_data", methods=['POST'])
def get_new_data():
    app.logger.info(
        "Browser sent the following via AJAX: %s", json.dumps(request.form))
    variable_to_return = request.form['please_return_data_of_this_variable']
    return jsonify({variable_to_return: MY_DATABASE[variable_to_return]})


SIMPLE_HTML_TEMPLATE = Template('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        {{ js_resources }}
        {{ css_resources }}
    </head>
    <body>
    {{ plot_div }}
    {{ plot_script }}
    </body>
</html>
''')


@app.route("/")
def simple():
    x = range(N_DATAPOINTS)
    y = MY_DATABASE[DEFAULT_VARIABLE]

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

    plot = figure(title="Flask + JQuery AJAX in Bokeh CustomJS")
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)
    callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var selected_value = cb_obj.value;
    var plot_data = source.data;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/get_new_data',
        data: {"please_return_data_of_this_variable": selected_value},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json_from_server) {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(json_from_server));
            plot_data.y = json_from_server[selected_value];
            source.change.emit();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Oh no, something went wrong. Search for an error " +
                  "message in Flask log and browser developer tools.");
        }
    });
    """)

    select = Select(title="Select variable to visualize",
                    value=DEFAULT_VARIABLE,
                    options=list(MY_DATABASE.keys()),
                    callback=callback)

    layout = column(select, plot)
    script, div = components(layout)
    html = SIMPLE_HTML_TEMPLATE.render(
        plot_script=script,
        plot_div=div,
        js_resources=INLINE.render_js(),
        css_resources=INLINE.render_css())

    return encode_utf8(html)

app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5002)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code. Do you know by chance if it is possible to replace built-in bokeh's Select by regular HTML select functionality? How to implement ajax call in that case? Usually ajax call is maid from .js file, not inside of flask app. I am trying to build an interactive flask app without bokeh sever avoiding the usage of built-in widgets. Any thought? Thanks

Comment: My pleasure! Unfortunately I don't know how to replace the built-in Bokeh select box. I would like to know how to do that as well, because I would like to use a searchable select box like Select2 since one of the apps that I've developed contains a select box with hundreds of items which makes it painful to scroll through the long list to find the item that you're looking for. If you will figure this out, please let me know :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will definitely let you know if I find the solution. At this point I really doubt that it is possible. Good luck to you too!

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I've been looking for