# Flask/Bokeh + AjaxDataSource + Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, bokeh

I read this useful [Flask + Bokeh AjaxDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083998/flask-bokeh-ajaxdatasource) and I was able to generate the sample plot.  I tried to modify the code in such a way to have the html file defined in the templates folder and let the flask to render_template the html file by passing the **div** and **script** elements as below:

```
script, div = components(fig)
return render_template('testajax.html', script = script, div = div)
```

and my HTML file is as follows:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %} 
<div class="container">
    <div>
        {{ script | safe}}
        {{ div | safe}}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

With the above changes, I will get these errors:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I think I do not have enough knowledge about the INLINE.render_js().

What is the issue and how can I resolve that?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: This does not seem to be a Bokeh issue. The error is coming from the operating system, and is saying that (for instance) the file you are trying to write to is already open by some other application. Perhaps you have the file open in an editor or web browser?

Comment: You are correct.  I do not get the windows error anymore.  However,  something is not correct since I cannot see any plots.  Should this work? or if I want to use AjaxDataSource I need to implement with INLINE.render_css() and INLINE.render_js().  Should I be able to implement it by using above HTML file?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually loading the BokehJS JavaScript and CSS anywhere? You need to do that as described here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components  Alternatively, you need to template in the inline JS and CSS yourself. The script that `components` returns assumes that BokehJS is already loaded *somehow*

Comment: In my template.html, I have loaded BokehJs and CSS with these lines:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bokeh-0.11.0.min.css') }}"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bokeh-0.11.0.min.js') }}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bokeh-widgets-0.11.1.min.css') }}"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bokeh-widgets-0.11.1.min.js') }}"></script>