# Bokeh: Implementing AJAX DataSource in Pyramid framework

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid, bokeh

I'm having a little trouble implementing a webpage that uses AJAX to update the bokeh plot embedded within an html page.

See below specific file where I'm trying to implement it:

https://github.com/hhprogram/PyramidSite/blob/master/webgraphing/views/ajaxView.py

You should be able to just clone the whole webgraphing repo to your machine to run the pyramid webpage locally. You can then run the pyramid serve using `pserve deveopment.ini` and then navigate to 'localhost:6543/bokehAJAX' in your browser. Looking at the javascript console it seems to be embedding the bokeh `div` in my html except the `div` has width of zero.

[image]

The ultimate goal is there should be a bokeh line graph figure on the page that periodically updates and adds data to the line graph. I'm not really too sure what I'm doing wrong here - any push in the right direction would be much appreciated. Note: I've tried looking at examples like: [Flask + Bokeh AjaxDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083998/flask-bokeh-ajaxdatasource) but to no avail.

Comment: What happens if you assign a width and height of 100% to the div?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's odd when I set the corresponding bokeh divs to have width and height 100% it doesn't change the div dimensions, I think it must be `div` that is returned must be empty. Think this was confirmed when I manually make the bokeh divs 400by400 pixels the bokeh div just shows up as a white block and no bokeh plot or default bokeh plot controls shown. Not sure why that's happening (even replaced my figure with a simple one and still nothing showed up)

Comment: Are there any errors in the Developer Tools Console or Network tabs?

Comment: Thanks @StevePiercy! Realized I got an `Uncaught Reference error: bokeh not defined` and looking back at some of the flask examples realized I needed `js_resources = INLINE.render_js()` and put that corresponding object into my jinja2 template. I'm still new to javascript so I'm unsure exactly what adding that does. I assume it defines/imports all the necessary variables and js libraries in order to properly render the bokeh javascript that I have injected into the html page?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my python code `ajaxView.py` file in the `bokeh_ajax` method, i was missing:

```
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
...

jsResources = INLINE.render_js()

...
return {..., 'jsResources': jsResources}
```

Then in my html / jinja2 template needed to add:

```
<head>
...
{{ jsResources | safe }}
...
</head>
```

Hope this helps someone else!