# Bokeh: CustomJS TextInput callback to adjust x axis range

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, bokeh

I'm trying to make a web page that has a plot powered by an AjaxDataSource object. However, I'd like to have a TextInput widget that can be used to changed the xrange of this plot. Below is a snippet:

```
source = AjaxDataSource(data={"time": [], "temperature": [], "id": []},
                        data_url='http://localhost:6543/AJAXdata',
                        polling_interval=100,
                        mode='append')
livePlot = figure(x_axis_type="datetime",
                  x_range=[startDt, endDt],
                  y_range=(0,25),
                  y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
                  title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43",
                  plot_width=800)
livePlot.line("time", "temperature", source=source)
....
updateStartJS = CustomJS(args=dict(xrange=livePlot.x_range), code="""
    var startStr = cb_obj.value
    alert(startStr)
    var newStartMilliSeconds = Date.parse(startStr)
    alert(newStartMilliSeconds)
    alert(xrange)
    alert(xrange.start)
    xrange.start = newStartMilliSeconds
    alert(xrange.start)
    xrange.change.emit();
""")
startInput = TextInput(value=startDt.strftime(dateFmt), callback=updateStartJS)
```

See this file and the `bokeh_ajax()` function for the complete implementation: https://github.com/hhprogram/PyramidSite/blob/master/webgraphing/views/ajaxView.py

When I run it and change the corresponding 'Start' textInput box. The CustomJS runs accordingly and per the alerts I have seen that it is capturing the correct new data (assuming you put in an ISO Formatted date like YYYY-mm-dd) but it fails to update the plot axis range (ie the plot doesn't change at all). How would I implement this? (I want to maintain the plots to have underlying AjaxDataSources as well and not use bokeh server - I already know how to implement this type of axis change functionality if running a bokeh server.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone curious, found my issue. Think the main problem was I was not putting the widget which I wanted to use to control the plot xrange and the actual plot itself within the same layout object. Therefore, when I was calling components on the plot object it didn't include the widget. Then when I included the widget with the plot it worked. See below updates and the updated github repo:

(credit to this post for significantly helping me: [Flask + Bokeh AjaxDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083998/flask-bokeh-ajaxdatasource))

complete file: https://github.com/hhprogram/PyramidSite/blob/master/webgraphing/views/ajaxView.py)

code snippet:

```
source = AjaxDataSource(data={"time": [], "temperature": [], "id": []},
                        data_url='http://localhost:6543/AJAXdata',
                        polling_interval=100,
                        mode='append')
livePlot = figure(x_axis_type="datetime",
                  x_range=[startDt, endDt],
                  y_range=(0,25),
                  y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
                  title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43",
                  plot_width=800)
livePlot.line("time", "temperature", source=source)
jsResources = INLINE.render_js()
cssResources = INLINE.render_css()

updateStartJS = CustomJS(args=dict(plotRange=livePlot.x_range), code="""
    var newStart = Date.parse(cb_obj.value)
    plotRange.start = newStart
    plotRange.change.emit()
""")

updateEndJS = CustomJS(args=dict(plotRange=livePlot.x_range), code="""
    var newEnd = Date.parse(cb_obj.value)
    plotRange.end = newEnd
    plotRange.change.emit()
""")

startInput = TextInput(value=startDt.strftime(dateFmt), title="Enter Date in format: YYYY-mm-dd")
startInput.js_on_change('value', updateStartJS)
endInput = TextInput(value=endDt.strftime(dateFmt), title="Enter Date in format: YYYY-mm-dd")
endInput.js_on_change('value', updateEndJS)
textWidgets = row(startInput, endInput)
# NOTE: this is important. Need to have the widgets and plot within same object that is the argument for components() method
layout =  column(textWidgets, livePlot)
script, div = components(layout)
```